# Conv1D input shape

Tags: keras-layer

I have this code that perfectly works.

```
input_shape = (1,3000,1000)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,3,activation='relu',input_shape=(3000,1000))(x)
print(y.shape)
```

> (1, 2998, 32)

I want to build on this basis a sequential model, but as i try the fit it gives me errors on the dimension.

Let's build the LABELS

```
l = np.random.randint(0,2,3000)
```

Then the model and the compiler

```
m =  tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32,3,activation='relu',input_shape=(3000,1000))
])
m.compile(optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'],loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

and finally let's fit the model

```
m.fit(x,l,epochs=2)
```

ERROR

> ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:   x sizes: 1   y sizes:
> 3000 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

can someone help me understand what's wrong ?

Comment: Removing a dimension from x and making it (3000,1000) gives another type of error in dimensions. 

Expected min ndim=3 , found ndim=2

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 training sample and 3000 labels.
shape of x and y are, x = (1,3000,3000) : y = (3000)

Comment: Inputshape to conv1d is 3000 1000 in first and second code example, not (1,3000) . Please detail your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.random.normal((3000,1000,1))
y = np.random.randint(1,2,3000)

tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(10,2,input_shape=(3000,1000))(x)

m=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                              tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(10,2,input_shape=(1000,1)),
                              tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                              tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
                              ])

m.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
m.fit(x,y,epochs=2)
```

In Keras Conv1D reference page [Keras Conv1D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D), it's written:"When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, e.g. (10, 128) for sequences of 10 vectors of 128-dimensional vectors, or (None, 128) for variable-length sequences of 128-dimensional vectors."

And endeed it works, but if conv1d is inserted in a sequential model the input_shape must be [0,1000,1]. I suppose because Sequential works on batches.